# Logic error with counter in my class

Tags: java, class, counter

The output I am looking for is for a returned value of 4 each time .getNumber() is called in main. Right now I am getting an output of 0 each time. First you will find my Car class with the counter, then an excerpt of my main where I create 4 objects then call the .getNumber() method.

```
public class Car{
  private String brand;
  private int year;
  private int price;
  private int number;
public Car(String b, int y, int p){
  brand = b;
  year = y;
  price = p;
}
public Car(){
  brand = "Chevy";
  year = 2005;
  price = 3000;
}
public String getBrand(){
  return brand;
}
public int getYear(){
  return year;
}
public int getPrice(){
  return price;
}
public int getNumber(){
  return number;
}   
public void setBrand(String b){
  brand = b;
}
public void setYear(int y){
  year = y;
}
public void setPrice(int p){
  price = p;
}
public void increment(){
  number++;
}   
}
Car car1 = new Car();
Car car2 = new Car("Ford", 2013, 20000);
Car car3 = new Car("Audi", 2012, 25000);
Car car4 = new Car();
  System.out.println("The total car number is: " + car1.getNumber());
  System.out.println("The total car number is: " + car2.getNumber());
  System.out.println("The total car number is: " + car3.getNumber());
  System.out.println("The total car number is: " + car4.getNumber());
```

Comment: Why do you think your code prints 0 each time?

Comment: I am using jgrasp on my laptop, and that is the output I am getting.

Comment: When I run the program this is my output:                                              The total car number is: 0
The total car number is: 0
The total car number is: 0
The total car number is: 0

Comment: No, that's not what I mean. I'm asking you to explain the flow. Why do you expect it to print something else?

Comment: increment() is never called. But that's not the only problem...

Comment: Oh wait, each time I'm creating a new car, I am also creating a new counter which means that is never reaching 4 because each car is only being created once.

Comment: But with a new counter each time, how am I supposed to be able to count up how many "cars" i create in my class. I understand that it can be done in main, but we were advised to try and find a way in the Car class itself.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your counter static. That way it is shared across all instances of the class. Then in your constructor you do counter++.

```
public class Car {
  private int number;
  private static int counter;
  public Car() {
    this.number = counter++;
  }
}
```